# Using Exchange GetAddressEntryFromID method with LDAP msExchMailboxGuid

Tags: outlook, ldap, exchange-server

Outlook COM has a method under Application.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID method to grab an address entry without having to iterate through the entire Global or All Users address book.

The issue is it is expecting the ID that an entry has under the AddressLists object.

In Active Directory, there is no equivalent that gives me the same GetAddressEntryFromId string.

I was previously making a list of all users, minus rooms and resources, by going through the entire COM object, but that takes too long; 20mins.

I figured if I use AD, which is faster, with filters to find the users, then I can grab the GUID and when looking for info on the user, not have to go through the entire COM object to grab it, but it will happen locally to the executable being run.

The issue I am having, as an example, is that I have a user with the following ID;

> 00000000DCA740C8C042101AB4B908002B2FE18201000000000000002F6F3D45766572657374205265696E737572616E63652F6F753D436F72702D48512F636E3D526563697069656E74732F636E3D6A6E6700

In AD the msExchMailboxGuid has a value of

> {4A49BD1C-62AE-4674-B097-C06528BDBEAE}

Not sure if these are the same, but I need to learn to better save it.

What else can I use, what can I do with the current time?

Answer (score 0):

GAL entry id is constructed from the EX address (which is stored in the legacyDN attribute).

The entry id you have above contains the following:

[image]

Comment: The main issue I am having is the following:

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: The main issue I am having is the following:

1. Iterating through COM object of `OutlookCOM.Session.AddressList["All Users"]` to go user by user and determine if it is a genuine person and not a room or Service Account takes 20 minutes.  Once I get the AddressEntry the idea is to get their FreeBusy property. That also takes time.  Alternatively, the COM object has a `OutlookCOM.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID(String)` which I thought would use the AD `msExchMailboxGuid` property...turns out not. So now I am stuck with AD's property and COM's property, but to get COM's property I have to

Comment: iterate through the COM object and again...takes time...Traversing AD is so much quicker since I can use the `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` class to do a filter and filters don't go through the entire AD object.  SOOOOOO much faster.

Comment: In Outlook, you can use Namespace.CreateRecipient / Recipient.Resolve - that will have the same effect as typing a name in the To edit box and hitting Ctrl+K to resolve the name.